# Making queries with two different tables in SQL/DBMS using basic relation algebra

Tags: sql, database, relational-database, relational-algebra

I am new to DBMS and SQL.  I need to run a query that uses two tables.  For example, I have a table of **users[ name, password, id, companyId]** and another table of **companies[ comp_name, companyID, netWorth]**. companyId links the two tables.  For every user, **I need to make a query that returns their name, comp_name, and netWorth** using basic rel alg operations.

Comment: What version of relational algebra are you using? What parts of this are you able to do? What example have you see like this? What has reading your text & googling suggested, since this is an absolutely basic question? What do you mean, tables in a DBMS yet operate on them via algebra?? EIther it's SQL or it's algebra. What exactly does your assignment say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `join` should do the trick:

```
SELECT u.name, c.comp_name, c.net_worth
FROM   users u
JOIN   companies c ON u.company_id = c.company_id
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the Query you are looking for   
  
(Just used the `=`, no `INNER JOIN` )  ; )

```
SELECT users.name, companies.comp_name, companies.netWorth
FROM companies, users
WHERE companies.companyID = users.companyId
```

Comment: While this will work, it's better to use the ANSI join syntax (e.g. using the INNER JOIN keyword) rather than an = sign to join tables, because it's clearer that a join is being performed instead of a filter, and it's easy to miss a join if you're writing queries in this way.

Comment: @bbrumm There is no difference between `,` and `cross join`, and no difference between `on` & `where`, except precedence, so your justfication is unsound. The only reason `on` was needed was for outer joins.

Comment: `,` is `cross join`, which is `inner join` `on` true. What is it you are trying to say? You are not clear. Emoticons don't make it clearer.

Comment: @philipxy - Yes, functionally there is no difference. However, the ANSI standard (JOIN keywords and ON) has been around for a long time and it is preferable to the old style (using = signs) for several reasons: Using "INNER JOIN t ON a=b" is clear that it's a join and not a row filter like "WHERE a=b". Also, for larger queries, it's easy to forget to add a join if you use "WHERE a=b" and get incorrect results. If you use the ANSI syntax your query won't run if you miss a JOIN.

Comment: @bbrumm I'll let my previous comment to you stand as a reply to that. However, I suggest you think through what you are trying to say, but not saying, regarding "using = signs". Also what your notion is that "it's a join [plus `on`]" is somehow different from "it's [a join plus] a filter". The `on`s & `where`s have *exactly the same expressions* and *exactly the same meaning*; they are *synonyms* with different *binding*, so whatever (ANSII/ISO) `,` says it says it exactly the way `join`s say it. I agree `on` facilitates localizing a join condition to a particular join without a nested select.